# たまには厳しい目で: 2015年6月のサイト自己評価

Tags: 討議

[スタック・オーバーフロー](http://ja.stackoverflow.com) はいいところですよね。でも世界には、問題を解決したくてもこのサイトの存在さえ知らない人がたくさんいます。Google からやってきたユーザーは、どんな第一印象を持つでしょうか？このサイトを初めてみる人の目線で、私たちが他のサイトに比べて優れているかどうかを考えてみましょう。

サイト自己評価期間中は、[専用のレビューキュー](https://ja.stackoverflow.com/review/site-eval)がオープンし、過去四半期に質疑応答が行われた質問を 10 個レビューすることができるようになります。 
個々の質問について Google で何回か検索して、簡単にそのQ&Aを見つけることができるかを確認し、他のサイトにある情報とこのサイトでの回答を比較してください。

質問のレビューは、サイト自己評価の一部にすぎません。クローズされるべきだったのに、クローズされなかった質問に一定のパターンはありますか？編集が必要な質問や回答は？うまくいっていることは？**以下に回答を投稿して意見を共有**し、これらの観点をはじめとしたサイトの健康状態について仲間のユーザーと話し合いましょう！

Comment: ボットはどのようにメッセージを送信できるのでしょうか? おお

Answer (score 2, accepted):

## 最終結果

- [swiftのHealthKitでHKHealthStore.authorizationStatusForTypeの挙動について](https://ja.stackoverflow.com/questions/9584/swift%e3%81%aehealthkit%e3%81%a7hkhealthstore-authorizationstatusfortype%e3%81%ae%e6%8c%99%e5%8b%95%e3%81%ab%e3%81%a4%e3%81%84%e3%81%a6)

**最終スコア:8** (優秀:8、満足:5、要改善: 0)

---

- [ng-repeat中に前の要素と比較して表示の出し分けをしたい](https://ja.stackoverflow.com/questions/9968/ng-repeat%e4%b8%ad%e3%81%ab%e5%89%8d%e3%81%ae%e8%a6%81%e7%b4%a0%e3%81%a8%e6%af%94%e8%bc%83%e3%81%97%e3%81%a6%e8%a1%a8%e7%a4%ba%e3%81%ae%e5%87%ba%e3%81%97%e5%88%86%e3%81%91%e3%82%92%e3%81%97%e3%81%9f%e3%81%84)

**最終スコア:8** (優秀:8、満足:3、要改善: 0)

---

- [IEで window.location.href に data:text/csv;... を設定することが出来ない](https://ja.stackoverflow.com/questions/9440/ie%e3%81%a7-window-location-href-%e3%81%ab-datatext-csv-%e3%82%92%e8%a8%ad%e5%ae%9a%e3%81%99%e3%82%8b%e3%81%93%e3%81%a8%e3%81%8c%e5%87%ba%e6%9d%a5%e3%81%aa%e3%81%84)

**最終スコア:3** (優秀:5、満足:8、要改善: 2)

---

- [Android アプリverCode取得](https://ja.stackoverflow.com/questions/9737/android-%e3%82%a2%e3%83%97%e3%83%aavercode%e5%8f%96%e5%be%97)

**最終スコア:2** (優秀:3、満足:12、要改善: 1)

---

- [Qt Creatorでwindows版のビルド](https://ja.stackoverflow.com/questions/9762/qt-creator%e3%81%a7windows%e7%89%88%e3%81%ae%e3%83%93%e3%83%ab%e3%83%89)

**最終スコア:1** (優秀:2、満足:10、要改善: 1)

---

- [Clojureでリストからマップを作るには](https://ja.stackoverflow.com/questions/10179/clojure%e3%81%a7%e3%83%aa%e3%82%b9%e3%83%88%e3%81%8b%e3%82%89%e3%83%9e%e3%83%83%e3%83%97%e3%82%92%e4%bd%9c%e3%82%8b%e3%81%ab%e3%81%af)

**最終スコア:1** (優秀:2、満足:8、要改善: 1)

---

- [symfony2のプロファイラの設定](https://ja.stackoverflow.com/questions/9849/symfony2%e3%81%ae%e3%83%97%e3%83%ad%e3%83%95%e3%82%a1%e3%82%a4%e3%83%a9%e3%81%ae%e8%a8%ad%e5%ae%9a)

**最終スコア:0** (優秀:2、満足:6、要改善: 2)

---

- [railsでpublicフォルダのファイルをレンダリングする方法](https://ja.stackoverflow.com/questions/9282/rails%e3%81%a7public%e3%83%95%e3%82%a9%e3%83%ab%e3%83%80%e3%81%ae%e3%83%95%e3%82%a1%e3%82%a4%e3%83%ab%e3%82%92%e3%83%ac%e3%83%b3%e3%83%80%e3%83%aa%e3%83%b3%e3%82%b0%e3%81%99%e3%82%8b%e6%96%b9%e6%b3%95)

**最終スコア:-1** (優秀:1、満足:10、要改善: 2)

---

- [ListFragment内でDLした画像（png）の保存方法を教えてください。](https://ja.stackoverflow.com/questions/10199/listfragment%e5%86%85%e3%81%a7dl%e3%81%97%e3%81%9f%e7%94%bb%e5%83%8f-png-%e3%81%ae%e4%bf%9d%e5%ad%98%e6%96%b9%e6%b3%95%e3%82%92%e6%95%99%e3%81%88%e3%81%a6%e3%81%8f%e3%81%a0%e3%81%95%e3%81%84)

**最終スコア:-1** (優秀:0、満足:10、要改善: 1)

---

- [Wheneverを使ってRakeタスクの実行時間を記録する方法](https://ja.stackoverflow.com/questions/9793/whenever%e3%82%92%e4%bd%bf%e3%81%a3%e3%81%a6rake%e3%82%bf%e3%82%b9%e3%82%af%e3%81%ae%e5%ae%9f%e8%a1%8c%e6%99%82%e9%96%93%e3%82%92%e8%a8%98%e9%8c%b2%e3%81%99%e3%82%8b%e6%96%b9%e6%b3%95)

**最終スコア:-3** (優秀:1、満足:2、要改善: 4)

---